# Movie where father, mother and son are the same person?

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama, time-travel

Does anyone know the name of the movie, where there is a cyclic story line, with a son, who his mother is trying to save or something like that, and happens that the son undergoes a sex change operation, and has sex with some guy to give birth to a kid, who is the son? Basically, the mother is her own son. And it also comes later where the father of the kid is also himself.

Answer (score 49):

[Predestination](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/)

> For his final assignment, a top temporal agent must pursue the one criminal that has eluded him throughout time. The chase turns into a unique, surprising and mind-bending exploration of love, fate, identity and time travel taboos.

Near the end of the movie :

> After returning to that day, John encounters Jane, and when they begin talking, John realizes he was Jane's lover. The baby born from this "self-fertilization" is taken by the agent to an orphanage 18 years earlier. **Therefore, Jane, John and their baby are the same person**, revealing a predestination paradox.
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_%28film%29#Plot)

Comment: Based on the Robert Heinlein short story All You Zombies. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies).

Comment: Your answer is formatted in such a way that it looks like you're referring to two different movies: one called *Predestination*, and another called *Near the end*. That's confusing.

Comment: @Jubobs Wow! It didn't even cross my mind that it may look that.

Comment: It's more like daughter, mother, and father are all the same person. The sex change operation is from female (mostly) to male.